# Calculate the volume of the body defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2≤1$ for which $x^2+z^2≥z$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

Calculate the volume of the body defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2≤1$ for which $x^2+z^2≥z$

Attempt:

For the volume, I used this formula: $V=\iint y(x,z)dxdz$

I find it easier to express the problem through $y$ instead of $z$, so I get the following:

$$y(x,z)= \sqrt{(1-x^2-z^2)}$$

$$x^2 + (z - \frac{1}{2 })^2 = ( \frac{1}{2} )^2$$

From these I can get the visual graph of the intersection and visualize the figure that I need to calculate the volume from.

Next I switch to polar coordinates:

$$x = r\cos(\phi)$$
$$z = r\sin(\phi)$$
$$|J| = r$$

From this, I get the integral bounds: $0 ≤ r ≤ \sin(\phi)$ and $0 ≤ \phi ≤ \pi$

For the first integral I get the following: $$\int \sqrt{1-r^2}rdr$$ with the respected bounds.

After the first integration, I get the following: $$ \frac{1}{3} \int (1-\cos^6(\phi))d\phi$$ with the respected bounds.

The final result is: $V = \dfrac{11\pi}{48}$.

Can anyone confirm if this is the correct result?

Comment: To @Vile: It seems fine to me.

Comment: I think the parametrization of $z$ should be $z = \dfrac{1}{2} + r \sin \phi $

Comment: I've evaluated the volume numerically (the figure is a solid sphere with a cylindrical hole through it).  The volume that I obtained of this figure is $V = 2.9833$ while $\dfrac{11 \pi}{48} = 0.7199$

Comment: Evaluating the iterated integral in Matthew's answer, the Volume comes to $$ \dfrac{4 \pi}{3} - \dfrac{4}{3} ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \dfrac{2}{3} )$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem asks you to compute the volume of the region *inside* the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and *outside* the cylinder $x^2+(z-1/2)^2=(1/2)^2$ whose boundary cannot be expressed in the form $y=f(x,z)$ for some $f$.

The volume of the region that is shared by both the cylinder and the sphere can be expressed as an iterated triple integral:

$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^{\sin(\theta)} \int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\mathrm{dy}r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$ Now subtract this from $4\pi/3$ to get your answer.